# discerning between "creation" and "creating"

Tags: meaning

But it seems that only the more eccentric or popular artists are viewed as true artists when working with items normally discarded in the trash pile. Why can’t average people be considered artists when they pull the same items out and mold them into some form of personal art of their own **creating**? Maybe it’s because we all have our own pre-set ideas of what art is and isn’t, or who artists are or should be.

I am wondering the reason why there has been used ***creating*** rather than ***creation***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Creation* is a noun meaning something that has been created - it would be the object that has been created.

*Creating*, when used as a noun, means the act of creating or a specific instance of the act of creating - it would be the actual activity of creating.